# Change timer interval in Azure for Azure Function published from Visual Studio

Tags: azure, timer, azure-functions

I have a function app with the following code

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

This executes my function every 5 seconds. In production I want the interval to be 30 seconds. After I publish the function to Azure it works and is run every 5 seconds.

On the top of the Integrate -page in the Function settings there is a message "Your app is currently in read-only mode because you have published a generated function.json. Changes made to function.json will not be honored by the Functions runtime" and the page is greyed out.

So how do I have different schedule for my timer function in development and production?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make your schedule configurable. Declare it like this in code:

```cs
[TimerTrigger("%schedule%")]
```

Then add the development setting named `schedule` with value `*/5 * * * * *` and production setting with value `*/30 * * * * *`.

Comment: This works. To clarify, the settings should be put in the Values settings
"Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxx",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "schedule": "*/5 * * * * *"
  }

Comment: I am unsure where to put this "Values" setting. Can I expose it as environment variable in "Application settings"?

Answer (score 10):

This should sum up the other answers given here:

**Configure local settings**

- add a [local.settings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) file to your project.
- insert the following code:

```
{
  "Values": { 
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXXXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXXXXXX", 
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXXXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXXXXXX", 
    "schedule": "*/5 * * * * *",
    "//": "put additional settings in here"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "XXXXXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

- set the trigger attribute like

```csharp
[TimerTrigger("%schedule%")]
```

**Configure Azure**

- go to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) and go to functions, click on your function and select `Application settings`
- in the application setting select `Add new setting`
- enter `schedule` as key and `*/30 * * * * *` as value
- click `save` on the top left
- redeploy your function

Comment: Is this documented somewhere official?

edit: found it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#configuration